# Switching git branch with ruby-git does not switch the files?

Tags: ruby, git, ruby-git

I am cloning a Github repo that has multiple branches, like for example:

```rb
root_dir    = Dir.mktmpdir(nil, Rails.root.join("repos").to_s)
root_folder = "ruby_git"
Git.clone("https://github.com/ruby-git/ruby-git.git", root_folder, :path => root_dir)
```

I then try to switch the branch to `"test"`:

```rb
g = Git.open(full_dir)
if g.current_branch != "test"
  puts g.branch("test").checkout # => "Switched to branch 'test'"
end
```

The branch switch is confirmed. I even test myself if the branch is correct:

```rb
puts g.current_branch # => "test"
```

But when I finally check the files like this:

```
puts Dir["#{full_dir}/tests/*"] # => Wrong files that belongs to the default branch...
```

I see that the folder still contains the files of the default branch, not the branch that I switched to.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is test the default branch?

Comment: Hi @LinFelix no it is not the default branch.

Comment: Does the "test" branch exist prior to this?

Comment: Sure it does. It's a standard repo whith two existing branches that I pull from remote. One is default, the other one is the one I would like switch to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself.

I need to pull the branch that I switched to:

```rb
g.pull("origin", "test")
```

The `pull` method is referenced [here](https://github.com/ruby-git/ruby-git/blob/58100b0135d39215330b9c63590dd6307bb54ea7/lib/git/base.rb#L390).